# Gradient descent multidimensional linear regression - does learning rate affects concurrency?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I wonder if gradient descent for multidimensional regression always finds the right result? I feel like this doesn't always have to be true. I have done some calculations and actually got correct results but not for all learning rates I tried to specify. It's not the case that it is too big, cause sometimes with even having too small learning rates I get wrong results. Please tell my if I make mistake in the calculations, or I'm wrong with divergence of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a convex loss function you always have one optimum point, and you will always be able to find it.

> I have done some calculations and I get correct results but not for all learning rates I tried to specify.

The reason is that you may have selected a large learning rate which may lead to overshoot the optimum. It also may be so small that you don't reach to the desired point and it all depends on your data. If you use the simple *gradient descent* algorithm, it is an incident that can be seen a lot. You can use other optimisation techniques like `Adam` which is much more better and you rarely see these problems.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but to take it a little further, I would say the reason that we choose the loss functions that we do is because they are convex.  If we change to say, logistic regression, we could still try to optimized for the residual sum of squares, but that will be non-convex for many datasets, were log loss is.  Even adding regularization can affect the convexity of linear regression, so we still perform gradient descent on RSS, but add boundary conditions on our coefficients.

Comment: @j.a.gartner I agree that RSS for logistic regression is not convex, that it is the reason people take the logarithm and make it convex.